# How do I write the definition of the function isEmpty() as a member function of class AnyList. Function returns true if the list is empty and false

Tags: c++

For this lab, you will need to create member functions of the class AnyList. Below you can find the interface of the class along with the definition of the Node class.

```cpp
class Node 
{ 

public: 
    Node() : data(0), ptrToNext(nullptr) {} 
    Node(int theData, Node *newPtrToNext)  
        : data(theData), ptrToNext(newPtrToNext){} 
    Node* getPtrToNext() const { return ptrToNext; } 
    int getData( ) const { return data; } 
    void setData(int theData) { data = theData; } 
    void setPtrToNext(Node *newPtrToNext)  
        { ptrToNext = newPtrToNext; } 
    ~Node(){} 
private: 
    int data;         
    Node *ptrToNext;  // Pointer that points to next node. 
}; 

class AnyList 
{ 

public: 
    AnyList() : ptrToFirst(nullptr), count(0) {} 
    // Other member functions of the class...  

private: 
    // Pointer to point to the first node in the list. 
    Node *ptrToFirst;  
    // Variable to store the number of nodes in the list. 
    int count;
```

Comment: Please include what you've tried and what specific problem you're running into.

Comment: I'm running into tackling this topic of a singly linked list, and how to get the function to return true if the list is empty. I've attempted using a bool

Comment: `~Node(){} ` -- Don't write empty-body destructors unless `Node` is going to be used polymorphically (in that case, the destructor would be `virtual`).  Either remove it, or specify `~Node() = default;`

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 3):

An empty list is initialized with `ptrToFirst` being a `nullptr`. So a reasonable implementation would be to check this equality:

```cpp
bool isEmpty() const {
    return ptrToFirst == nullptr;
}
```

Alternatively, you could check that the `count` is `0`:

```cpp
bool isEmpty() const {
    return count == 0;
}
```